# Submit a two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
checkdata['attendance_batch'] = [
    {user_id_c: 'abcda', ispresent: 0},
    {user_id_c: 'abxcda', ispresent: 2},
    {user_id_c: 'abctda', ispresent: 1}
]
```

I want my array in the above mentioned format in javascript

MY HTML:

```
<label for='flip'>" + entry["name"] + "</label><div id='switch'><select name='user_id_c' id='flip2b' iduser='"+entry["id"]+"' data-role='slider'><option value='1'>Present</option><option value='0'>Absent</option></select>


$("#frmattendance").submit(function(event) {


event.preventDefault();
$form = $(this);

var a = {};

var paramString = [];
$($form).find(':input').each(function() {

    //console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    if ($(this).val() == 'Mark') {
    }

    else {

        a[{user_id_c: $(this).attr('iduser'), ispresent: $(this).val()}];
        //  console.log(a[$(this).attr('name')]);
    }

});

 var $sessiondata = sessionStorage.sessionid;


$.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: saverecordurl + 'pcc_attendance',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            // session_id: $sessiondata,
            //json object to sent to the authentication url
            data: {checkdata: a, session_id: $sessiondata},
            success: function(response) {
                //console.log(response);
                if (response.id !== null)
                {

                    alert("You have successfully marked the attendance");

                    $.mobile.changePage("#eventdetails", {
                        transition: "slide",
                        reverse: true,
                        changeHash: true
                    });

                }

            },
            error: function(result) {
                $.mobile.changePage("#one", {
                    transition: "slide",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: true
                });
            }

        })
```

});

Could someone help me with the format am i making a mistake?

Comment: What is the HTML doing there?

Comment: getting data from html and forming the array

Comment: That is an array of objects, not a two-dimensional array.  I am not quite sure what you are asking though. When you say you want to "submit" this data, do you mean like in a POST?

Comment: No, I mean `<label for='flip'>" + entry["name"] + "</label>` produces a label with `" + entry["name"] + "` as the label text, for example. The JavaScript here isn't in a `<script>` tag so it'll never execute.

Comment: @MikeBrant Please chk my edited code

Comment: Why not just build your form fields in a sane fashion and use `$.serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[{user_id_c: $(this).attr('iduser'), ispresent: $(this).val()}];` is invalid syntax. You could do one of the following:

```
var a = {
   user_id_c: $(this).attr('iduser'),
   ispresent: $(this).val()
}
```

or

```
var a = {}
...
a.user_id_c = $(this).attr('iduser');
a.ispresent = $(this).val()
```

Comment: Thanks but woudn't it just append the last value and not append all of them. i have multiple elements with same name on my form to mark attendance

Comment: `checkdata.attendance_batch.push(a);` would add them to your checkdata array

Comment: attendance_batch.push(a); i did this it seems to be ovveriting my data

Comment: it looks like you are only passing the last `a` defined, rather than the collection of them (`data: {checkdata: a, session_id: $sessiondata},`), initialize the attendance_batch array prior to your `input.each`, then pass the `attendance_batch` var in your `post` call